# How to use http_query(params)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to set Facebook graph result code on params but i can't do it.

how toi use http_query(params) with graph code?

graph code:

```
{
  "about": "Nothing To Say...",
  "id": "126719904567117"
}
```

and
`http_query(params)`

I am new in coding.

I am trying like this:

```
http_query(params, "about": "Nothing To Say...", "id": "126719904567117")
```

Please tech me and solve this issue. thanks

**Updated**

```
let params = {
        locale: 'en_US',
        client_country_code: 'US',
        fb_api_req_friendly_name: 'save_core_profile_info',
        access_token: token_user
    };
    params.work = JSON.stringify([{
        "id": student,
        "privacy": '{"value":"EVERYONE"}',
        "ref": "nux_android"
    }]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me',
        data: params
    })
```

i am using this. now i wants to set `about` same as `params.work`

params.work grap code;

```
{
  "work": [
    {
      "employer": {
        "id": "452244444871895",
        "name": "Student"
      },
      "start_date": "0000-00",
      "id": "101871430385298"
    }
  ],
  "id": "126719904567117"
}
```

Comment: What is the `http_query` function you are referring to?

Comment: `let params` and `params.educations`. actually i don't understand your question.

Comment: _"now i wants to set `about` same as `params.work`"_ Set `about` where?

Comment: @QuynhNguyenVan See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get property, value pairs of a plain object and `URLSearchParams()` to create a query string using the array values

```
let o = {
  "about": "Nothing To Say...",
  "id": "126719904567117"
};

let entries = Object.entries(o);

let params = new URLSearchParams();

for (let [key, prop] of entries) params.set(key, prop);
```

Comment: i am using this: params.education = JSON.stringfy({
    id: something, )}

Comment: @QuynhNguyenVan You can use the same pattern at Answer to achieve expected result. Substitute the plain object that you are using for value at `o` at Answer

Comment: like this: params.languages = JSON.stringify([{
     id: english,
     privacy: '{"value": "EVERYONE"}',
     ref: "nux_android"
 }]);
params.relationship_status({
        single,
     privacy: '{"value": "EVERYONE"}',
     ref: 'nux_android'
 });

Comment: Why is `JSON.stringify()` necessary if requirement is to create a query string from an object? What is expected result?

Comment: `params.languages` `params.about` and `params.relationship` not working on my script. i don't need this `"id": "126719904567117"`. just need `"about": "Nothing To Say...",`. your answer workable?

Comment: @QuynhNguyenVan It is not clear what input and expected result are. Is requirement to  a) create a query string from a plain object; b) create a query string from a string; or c) neither a) or b)?

Comment: ok, last sentence, can i update facebook profile about using graph api explorer?

Comment: @QuynhNguyenVan Not sure. How is that related to Question?

Comment: i tried without about, language and interest in. i success. i can update education,work etc. now i wants make about update system. but i don't understand how to i add about data on params.

Comment: `params.about = /* value */`?

Comment: Not familiar with *acebook api. Where is `"about"` property expected to be set?

Comment: i also tried `params.about = ' i am simple man'` but not updated on about section on facebook. i used access token for all process.

Comment: Again, have not tried *acebook api. At which object is `"about"` expected to be set?

Comment: Have no means to verify what you are trying here.

Comment: i don't understand `At which object is "about" expected to be set`. its a profile details.

Comment: If you are passing an object as a `JSON` string, am not certain  which object the `"about"` property is expected by the api to be set at. Have not tried the api of the site that you are referencing.

Comment: its a `json data`. i get it from graph explorer

Comment: i think so, I don't get solution for my weak english. thanks for reply me.

Comment: @QuynhNguyenVan No worries. english is not the issue. At least you are trying. Can you include link to documentation for the api that you are using and what `http_query` is at Question?